# AMPScript color highlighting not working in VSCode

Tags: ampscript, visualstudiocode

I'm no longer seeing color syntax highlighting for AMPScript in VS Code when using the AMPScript extension. Does anyone know if there's a fix for this? I think this started after a recent VS Code update, but I couldn't be sure.

VS Code version 1.45.0

AMPScript extension (sergey-agadzhanov.ampscript) version 1.4.3

Windows 10

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The file have to be saved with .amp or .ampscript extension

[image]